# iOS10 Speech Recognizer Spelling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, speech-recognition

I managed to implement SpeechRecognizer by recording audio from mic. The transcribe is ok but I am looking for an option for user to use either Words OR Spelling.

For example, if user want to spell something, he just tap a button, and the "spelling mode" is activated and then user can spell a word as he like for example "CNN" or "ABC". As of now when I say "CNN", Siri transcribe that to "See and and".. which is not correct.

Does SpeechRecognizer have such feature? Or any idea how to approach this goal?

**EDIT**: I prefer ObjC (because Im a stubborn noob). But if you have swift example, that's ok too I can try to translate into ObjC myself.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I have a little tricky tip to solve your issue! I did for a small POC when I used Speech Recognizer. By this way, try to register in your device, as new contact "CNN" or "ABC".

Like this SpeechRecognizer will be able to recognize specific name and obviously also some words.

Comment: It could work I guess but cannot be implemented to my app since I cannot ask all my app users to install CNN and ABC contact.

Comment: Of course, that make sense. I tough you wanted just make a POC like I did when I used Speech Recognizer.  If you achieve to fix your issue, please post the answer, I want to know the proper way too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting taskHint of speech recognition request with SFSpeech​Recognition​Task​Hint​Dictation

```
speechRecognitionRequest.taskHint = SFSpeechRecognitionTaskHintDictation;
```

> SFSpeech​Recognition​Task​Hint​Dictation
>   The request is for recognition of general dictation.

You can find more details on [Speech Recognition Task Hints](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognitiontaskhint?language=objc)